# 'const' in C language may be redundant?

Tags: c

I have been confusing with const in the C language. I think if no const conception, all the programme existed in the world also could run smoothly.so Can anyone help me and give me some explanation.

Comment: using variable replace const but I don't change it

Comment: It helps to avoid errors where you accidentally change something that you did not want to change, or is not allowed to change

Comment: Anything beyond machine language is redundant, so what is your point?

Comment: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html

Comment: It also tells the compiler the nature of the variable/value. Gives a hint to the optimiser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you removed `const`, most<sup>1</sup>  C code would continue to work as it does today.

However, `const` really exists to save the programmer from himself. The `const` modifier on a function parameter says: "this function promises to not modify the object this points to." So if you forget, and try to modify the object, the compiler will stop you.

1 - I say "most" because `const` can also have a runtime effect. Statically-allocated objects marked `const` will typically be placed in a read-only section in the program image, and this data is marked as read-only when the program is loaded. So if you were to cast away the `const` and try to write to this object, your program will segfault. The crash here is desired. Because it prevents your program from running with invalid assumptions about its data.

Answer (score 1):

No, is not redundant at all. The qualifier `const` is usually applied to the declaration of any variable to specify that its value will not be changed during the program execution (Which depends upon where const variables are stored, we may change value of const variable by using pointer). If you have ever programmed in Java, is similar to an static variable.

You can read more about `const` here: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/const_and_volatile.html

Answer (score 0):

const will make the assembly code into an absolute number value. It will not be a register or memory value and can't be modified by the code of course. It makes for fast program operation because it doesn't load the value from memory or a register.

However, most optimized coding already does this in assembly when it realizes the value isn't changed.

John

Comment: You do not need you name at the end

Comment: thanks. Your explanation absolutely help me. So if I don't consider the  program running speed and code safer, can I write code without const??

Comment: *"const will make the assembly code into an absolute number value."* This is incredibly vague. You seem to be referring to one specific optimization that a compiler might perform, where a value, if known to never change, can be placed in the *immediate* value of the instruction, instead of being read from memory.